# ES6: How may one reference an instance method bound to "this"?

Tags: javascript, methods, binding, ecmascript-6

Take the following ES6 code:

```
class MyClass {
    constructor() {
        this.attribute = 'test'
    }

    myMethod() {
        console.log(this.attribute)
    }
}

// works - prints 'test'
var instance = MyClass()
instance.myMethod()

// doesn't work - outputs "undefined".  "this" isn't bound to the function.
var methodRef = instance.myMethod
methodRef()
```

Initially, I had expected that the second example would have bound "this" to the method, but after thinking it though it makes sense if `instance.method(arg)` is syntactic sugar for `method(instance, arg)`. First of all - is it simply syntactic sugar? In ES5, most "class" implementations don't have this issue. Secondly, is there a way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

NOTE: I am using [es6-transpiler](https://github.com/termi/es6-transpiler), which may be buggy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think javascript has the concept of bound method, which means methodRef has noting to do with instance.

So:

`instance.myMethod()` is equivalent with `methodRef.call(instance)`

`methodRef()` is equivalent with `methodRef.call()`

I think what you looking for is: `var methodRef = instance.myMethod.bind(instance)`